# Prolog, on start executing write something

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I want to display a string on terminal when the user executes it. But, I want to do this without calling any predicate. For example, if the code is like this:

```
print_sth(String):-write(String).
```

it will print some string only if I make an explicit call of that predicate. Instead, when we consult our program I want the view to be something like this:

```
This is a brief tutorial of the program that was called automatically. 
?- // Ready to call a predicate here, but the string above was displayed when we consulted the program.
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
:- write('This is a brief tutorial of the program that was called automatically. ').
some_predicate():- do_sth().
// ... other stuff follows here.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain more precisely, *I tried this* (did you type that directly into a file and include it? Type it at the prompt? Was the `:-` something you typed or was it a prompt?) and please explain more precisely, *but it didn't work* (Error message? Unexpected results?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:- [initialization](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28initialization%29/1)(writeln('hello world')).